# babel 7 how to connect polyfill correctly?

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer, webpack, babeljs

How to connect polyfill correctly?
I read all the documentation Babel 7 and followed it. Below you can see my settings.
if I add this in the webpack config

```
entry: [
    'core-js/stable',
    'regenerator-runtime/runtime',
    './main.js'
],
```

then everything works. but according to the documentation this line can be removed, since all the settings in the babel.config.js

If i remove from entry this line, redux store not working in IE11

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = function (api) {
    api.cache(true);

    return {
        presets: [
            [
                '@babel/preset-env',
                {
                    debug: true,
                    useBuiltIns: 'entry',
                    corejs: {
                        version: '3.6',
                        proposals: false
                    },
                }
            ],
            '@babel/preset-react',
            'rsuite'
        ],
        plugins: [
            'react-hot-loader/babel',
            '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
            '@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from',
            '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread',
            '@babel/plugin-syntax-object-rest-spread',
            '@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions',
            '@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator',
            '@babel/plugin-transform-classes',
            '@babel/plugin-transform-parameters',
            '@babel/plugin-transform-property-literals',
            ['@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
                {
                    corejs: {
                        version: 3,
                        proposals: true
                    }
                }
            ],
            '@babel/plugin-transform-spread',
            '@babel/plugin-transform-template-literals',
            'babel-plugin-styled-components',
        ]
    };
};
```

package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.9.5",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-object-rest-spread": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-classes": "^7.9.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-parameters": "^7.9.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-property-literals": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-spread": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-template-literals": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.9.4",
    "@devexpress/dx-react-grid-material-ui": "^2.4.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
    "babel-helper-annotate-as-pure": "^7.0.0-beta.3",
    "babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.10.7",
    "babel-preset-rsuite": "^4.0.1",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "colors": "^1.3.2",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.2",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^16.1.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.11.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "file-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "less": "^3.8.1",
    "less-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.7.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.1",
    "react-highlight-words": "^0.10.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.7.2",
    "redux-saga": "^0.16.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.3",
    "webpack": "^4.42.1",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.6.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.9.2",
    "@babel/runtime-corejs3": "^7.9.2",
    "@hot-loader/react-dom": "^16.13.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "c3": "0.4.11",
    "cookie": "^0.3.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "date-fns": "^2.0.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "js-base64": "^2.5.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "normalizr": "^3.3.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "query-string": "^5.1.1",
    "ramda": "^0.26.1",
    "rc-tree": "^3.1.1",
    "react": "^16.8.3",
    "react-datepicker": "^2.8.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.3",
    "react-html-parser": "^2.0.2",
    "react-paginate": "^6.3.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.0-rc.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.4.0-beta.7",
    "react-scrollbar": "^0.5.6",
    "react-select": "^2.4.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.5",
    "reselect": "^3.0.1",
    "rsuite": "^4.1.4",
    "styled-components": "^4.1.3"
  }
```

webpack rules

```
module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: 'babel-loader',
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: cssLoaders()
            },
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: cssLoaders('less-loader')
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|svg|gif?)$/,
                use: 'file-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf?)$/,
                use: 'file-loader'
            },
        ]
    },
```

Comment: and i have .browserlistrc with IE11

Comment: `entry` option is basic in webpack file. It is the first file you want Webpack to start with. I didn't find the information about that we can remove the option. Could you please provide the documentation link that you find this information? I suggest that you can just keep `entry` if the app works well with it.

Comment: i keep it mind remove 'core-js/stable' and 'regenerator-runtime/runtime' from entry.

Comment: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill search line "With webpack"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is due to the fact that the react does not support ie10. I get an error in ie10 Set in undefined and in ie11 the redux store is not loaded. According to the documentation, the react needs to be imported polyfill globally.
https://reactjs.org/docs/javascript-environment-requirements.html

Answer (score 1):

Just don't remove these lines you've added for the polyfills

```
entry: [
    'core-js/stable',
    'regenerator-runtime/runtime',
    './main.js'
],
```

You are doing right, give us the link to the documentation where it is said this line can be removed. I think it's a misunderstanding.

Or maybe you are missing an other babel plugin ;)

## UPDATE 2020-04-17

As it is said for `@babel-polyfill`

> As of Babel 7.4.0, this package has been deprecated in favor of directly including core-js/stable (to polyfill ECMAScript features) and regenerator-runtime/runtime (needed to use transpiled generator functions):

So install `npm i core-js` and `npm i regenerator-runtime`

Then in your webpack config file you manage the entry points like that

```
...
  entry: {
    bundle: [require.resolve('core-js/stable'), require.resolve('regenerator-runtime/runtime'), paths.srcClient]
  },
...
```

Then you are good to go

Comment: why do i need a line useBuiltIns in babel config?

Comment: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill search line "With webpack"